# Executing commands from MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to execute a command such as `db.eval("return new Date()")` from MongoDB Compass?

Right now I see only collection query commands like filter, project, sort, etc.

Comment: db.eval is `deprecated since version 3.0`

Answer (score 3):

Mongo compass provides only filter option (Query Bar) to do queries on specific collection :(

You can read how it works - https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/schema/#query-bar

Answer (score 1):

Replying to old thread: Just want to mention that Mongo Compass v1.22 and newer has Embedded Shell which can do shell commands https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/embedded-shell/

Answer (score 1):

to anyone still finding where the command line is, here it is

[image: _MONGOSH]